# I have a problem in setup flutter when i was installed flutter in my computer (arabic lang) and the computer cant read dart.exe

Tags: flutter, windows, dart, installation, flutter-doctor

I have a problem in setup flutter  when i was installed flutter    in my computer (arabic lang)
Flutter (Channel master, 3.16.0-20.0.pre.35, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3570], locale ar-EG)
• Flutter version 3.16.0-20.0.pre.35 on channel master at C:\flutter
! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to C:\dart\bin\dart.exe, which is not inside your current Flutter SDK
checkout at C:\flutter. Consider adding C:\flutter\bin to the front of your path.

the dart.exe is already existed in the C:\dart\bin\dart.exe and in the C:\flutter\bin
but the error still
note: the language of my computer is Arabic

Comment: every thing goes well after i turn the language into English

Answer (score -1):

every thing goes well after i turn the language into English